# Can we include another Makefile in a GNU Makefile by using the relative path?

Tags: makefile, gnu

I have a Makefile in:

```
project/all_app/myapp/src/Makefile
```

I also have a master Depend.mk in

```
project/Depend.mk
```

Can I include the main Makefile by using the relative path?

```
include ../../../../Depend.mk
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make include in makefiles be relative to the file's location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074372/make-include-in-makefiles-be-relative-to-the-files-location)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be warned that make's include starts at pwd, *not* the path to the Makefile. (so `make -f` will probably cause problems)

Answer (score 7):

The rules for include in make are a little bit complex - see [this section](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) of the GNU make manual. But yes - you can do what you asked.