# Make include in makefiles be relative to the current file's location

Tags: makefile, cygwin, android-ndk

Directly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071248/make-within-ndk-gdb-chokes-on-relative-path-in-android-mk). How can I make the `include` directive in makefiles behave relatively to the location of the **currently executing** makefile.

Assume that the **current** path is arbitrary and you have no control over it. Only the makefile location is known. Your makefile is not the root one from the `make` invokation - it's included. That's exactly how it is in Android NDK.

Is there a builtin variable with the current makefile's name or path (as opposed to the root level makefile)? Can I strip filename away from it, leaving just the path? Using make 3.81 on Cygwin.

Comment: The question is unclear: you're saying the makefile location is known. Then, you've got no question anymore!

Comment: Include looks in the current folder, and in the folder where the initial makefile is. My makefile is included from the initial makefile; include doesn't work as expected. That said, I've found a workaround years ago - I made an env variable with the project location.

Comment: So, you didn't even use the answers. Sigh. BTW, the folder of the initial makefile is not in the include path.

Comment: None of them worked for both `ndk-build` and `ndk-gdb` :( And now the NDK build architecture is completely different anyway.

Answer (score 30):

You can get the name of the makefile being currently processed from [`MAKEFILE_LIST` builtin variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables).

Given that the current makefile is **the last one** that has been included (in other words you didn't use another `include` directive since the beginning of the current script), the path to the script itself would be:

```
SELF_DIR := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
```

Now you are able to include a script in the same directory as such (note an absence of slash, it has already been added by `$(dir ...)`):

```
include $(SELF_DIR)another.mk
```

Note: In GNU Make 3.80 there was no `lastword` builtin function. In that case you may implement it as follows replacing `$(lastword ...)` with `$(call lastword,...)`:

```
lastword = $(if $(firstword $1),$(word $(words $1),$1))
```

Comment: In my case, MAKEFILE_LIST returns something unrelated.

Comment: It seems strange, I just tried the solution on Cygwin too, everything works as expected...

What's the value of `MAKEFILE_LIST` in your case?

Comment: Dunno, but the path that came out /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r6b/buil
d/core/ . This is Android NDK, and my makefile is but a tiny fragment in a sizable build framework.

Comment: The only left idea is to check that you assign `SELF_DIR` as the first statement of your makefile, before including anything else. Also the assignment must be simple (`:=`), not recursive (`=`).

Comment: As the name implies, ``MAKEFILE_LIST`` is a list and may contain more than just the current makefile.  You can't rely it on to always point to the current Makefile.

Comment: @pimlottc that is exactly what `lastword` is for.

Comment: Beware that using `MAKEFILE_LIST` will break your Makefile if you include any other Makefiles and you expect to support paths with spaces in them.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a builtin variable with the current makefile's name?

Yes, there is, use ${CURDIR}. This is the directory where top-level Makefile is located, so you don't need to strip anything from it.

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion

Comment: Good one, but there's catch. CURDIR, it seems, is sometimes terminated with / (when invoking ndk-gdb) and sometimes (ndk-build) is not. Any way around that?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, as foo//bar is a legal path and it equals foo/bar. So you may just use ${CURDIR}/...

Comment: Funny... Now ndk-build works and ndk-gdb behaves as if CURDIR is one level up above my project location. Now I'm utterly puzzled.

Comment: I dont think the op asked what you answered. From the manual "[...] in particular note that if you include files from other directories the value of CURDIR does not change". So you cannot use it to figure an included makefile directory.

Comment: So wrong. `$(CURDIR)` is not at all related to any Makefile location. It's just the dir the initial make command was launched from (and doesn't change when recursively calling make).

Answer (score 2):

I find that relative paths work (GNUMake 3.81), but if they don't for you, try this:

```
include $(abspath ../whatever)
```

Comment: Good one, but on ndk-gdb builds it resolves wrongly, goes one level up too many. I guess the assumtion is that the relative path is relative to the current directory (as opposed to the file's directory) is still there.

Comment: Repeated error: this does not work for out-of-tree builds.

Comment: Not sure it answers the OP question, but man did it help me !! ...so Thanks