# Makefile failed to generate output with folder structure

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

Below is the Makefile I have created where
source codes,
header files and
Makefile all are in the same folder.

This Makefile gives correct result and generate the output

```
all : main

main : main.o 
    gcc -Wall -Werror -o main main.o 

main.o : main.c main.h 
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c -MMD -MP main.c

clean: 
    rm -f *.o main
```

When I create folder structure as follows

```
work
├── inc/
│   └── main.h files here
├── src/
│   └── main.c files here
├── _Build/
│   └── Makefile here
```

Modified Makefile is

```
all : main

main : main.o 
    gcc -Wall -Werror -o main main.o 

main.o : ../src/main.c ../inc/main.h 
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c -MMD -MP $<

clean: 
    rm -f *.o main
```

I am getting this error, though the path of the folders are set correctly

```
  gcc -Wall -Werror -c -MMD -MP ../code/src/main.c
 ../code/src/main.c:4:10: fatal error: main.h: No such file or directory
 #include "main.h"
      ^~~~~~~~
 compilation terminated.
 make: *** [Makefile:16: main.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not specifically with make, but with the include paths. The `#include ""` statement will use the relative path based on the current source file.  If you modify the include statement in main.c as:

```
#include "../inc/main.h"
```

it will find your header. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Operation.html for the corresponding documentation.

The other way is (if you want to solve it from the Makefile) is to pass the `inc` dir as an include path to gcc, by using the -I command line option:

```
gcc -I./inc -Wall -Werror -c -MMD -MP $<
```

See at http://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/3/rhel-gcc-en-3/directory-options.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One question is while using -I command line option, exact path is not needed like -I ../inc

Comment: Welcome. I fixed the blindly copy-pasted line for the -I usage example.

Comment: The path passed to -I can be either relative or absolute. One way to handle this is use relative paths based on the Makefile's path, see for example this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074372/make-include-in-makefiles-be-relative-to-the-files-location

Comment: Thanks once again for your guidance.